# NSInternalInconsistencyException ( error during execution of SQL string 'INSERT INTO Y_UBMETA(YPEERID, YTRANSACTIONNUMBER) )

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, icloud, icloud-api

iOS iCloud

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'error during execution of SQL string 'INSERT INTO Y_UBMETA(YPEERID, YTRANSACTIONNUMBER)

Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134312 "Store metadata recovery appears to have failed, please try adding the store to the coordinator again. If that is unsuccessful, migrate the data to a new ubiquitized persistent store." UserInfo=0xdba5b80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Store metadata recovery appears to have failed, please try adding the store to the coordinator again. If that is unsuccessful, migrate the data to a new ubiquitized persistent store.}, {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Store metadata recovery appears to have failed, please try adding the store to the coordinator again. If that is unsuccessful, migrate the data to a new ubiquitized persistent store.";

How do I solve this problem? Coz that it is an internal query for iCloud. I am putting my code block below of the method i have written..

```
    - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
 {
     NSLog(@"persistentStoreCoordinator:%@",[persistentStoreCoordinator_ description]);
     if((persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil)) 
     {
         return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
     }

     NSLog(@"persistentStoreCoordinator:%@",[persistentStoreCoordinator_ description]);
     NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataModel.sqlite"];

     persistentStoreCoordinator_ = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];


     NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc = persistentStoreCoordinator_;

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
             
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
         NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

         // Migrate datamodel
         NSDictionary *options = nil;

         // this needs to match the entitlements and provisioning profile
         NSURL *cloudURL = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

         NSLog(@"cloudURL:%@",cloudURL);

             //NSString* coreDataCloudContent = [[cloudURL path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];  
             
            cloudURL = [cloudURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];                                                                                                                                   

        // NSLog(@"coreDataCloudContent:%@",coreDataCloudContent);


        //if ([coreDataCloudContent length] != 0 && [[defaults objectForKey:@"allMetadataFlag"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) 
             
        if (cloudURL )//&& [[defaults objectForKey:@"allMetadataFlag"] isEqualToString:@"YES"])
             
         {
             // iCloud is available
            // cloudURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:coreDataCloudContent];

             NSLog(@"cloudURL:%@",cloudURL);

             options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                        @"SecureAssistant.store", NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey,
                        cloudURL, NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey,nil];
         } 
         else 
         {
             // iCloud is not available
             options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                        [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,nil];
         }
             NSError *error = nil;
         [psc lock];
         if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
         {
             NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
             abort();
         }
         [psc unlock];

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             NSLog(@"asynchronously added persistent store!");
             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RefetchAllDatabaseData" object:self userInfo:nil];
         });

     });
    
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue, it happened because i have changed the attribute of datamodel from Xcode, not from my app by code. i solved this by delete the SQLite file from iCloud and deleted the app from device then rebuild. It worked for me.